# copy email address from group of emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

we have a mailing list with bounce backs going into a outlook account. is there an easy way for me to copy all the email addresses out of a group of emails in outlook so i can remove them from my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article ["How Can I List the Addresses in My Sent Items Folder in an Excel Spreadsheet?"](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/09/05/how-can-i-list-the-addresses-in-my-sent-items-folder-in-an-excel-spreadsheet.aspx)